# Silverstripe many-many relationship for CheckboxSetField

Tags: arrays, checkbox, many-to-many, silverstripe

I have a `CheckboxSetField` with numbers 1 - 10. I also have a many-many relationship set up that gets updated with the numbers.

While I can select numbers no problem, I am having trouble calling those selected numbers again once it has been submitted.

```
CheckboxSetField::create("Numbers","Numbers")
            ->setSource(array("1" => "1",
                             "2" => "2",
                             "3" => "3",
                             "4" => "4",
                             "5" => "5",
                             "6" => "6",
                             "7" => "7",
                             "8" => "8",
                             "9" => "9",
                             "10" => "10",))
            ->setInline(true)
            ->addExtraClass("inline-checkbox")
            ->setDefaultItems($numberlist)
```

I set up a query that returns all the numbers to `setDefaultItems`.
It returns the numbers as a string which I then convert to an array but the array returns

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 )
```

If the array is:

```
(array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "3"))
```

It seems to work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$numberlist` seems to only contain the numbers as values, but you need keys and values.

You can achieve that using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), example:

```
->setDefaultItems(array_combine($numberlist, $numberlist))
```

**Hint:** to create numeric ranges, you can use the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function, so you could shorten your `setSource` code to:

```
->setSource(array_combine(range(1,10), range(1,10)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps!

Comment: Just one more thing on this. Is there a reason why when I deselect an option it doesn't update the DB except for number 1? When 1 is unchecked it deletes from the DB but any other number will be checked again once the page reloads. Thanks

Comment: Is "Numbers" your `many_many` relation? I can't really help without knowing your setup.

Comment: That is correct yes. Numbers is the name of the Number table

Comment: You shouldn't use `setSource` if you're dealing with relation data. If your relations don't contain these items, it won't work. You'll need to add the numbers 1-10 to your "Numbers" table instead of using "setSource" with an array.